make sure ANGLE OpenGL es 2.0 libraries are installed
I encountered the error:



Few times and every time I had to search for these libraries, where is this ANGLE library prebuilt libEGL.dll,libGLESv2.dll d3dcompiler_*.dll? it's github page says only to build from scratch.
(Yeah my cpu is too old to not support opengl)
P.S. Thinking stackoverflow is not good for this question am asking her + need to post this to some community because I think many will find this useful, searching for this question I get no easy answer, and I myself wasted half an hour on this third time

Found from here https://groups.google.com/g/angleproject/c/j97Ps7gtkug?pli=1,
Go to chrome directory:

in directory see \Application\version Application\130.0.6723.70 in my case.
get required files from here.
copy-paste in your application directory(look into folders in/near your bin directory/directory of executable of error app) paste it along with other dlls + copy it somewhere else for later use.

